# What is the difference in size between a decoded and encoded image

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

In the [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) there is a section entitled "Known iOS Resource Limits." In this section they warn:

> The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM.

Then go on to note that there is large different in decoded vs encoded image sizes

> Note that the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size of an image.

So assume I have a .png image on my hard drive that says it's 2794 × 1859 = ~ 5,400,000 pixels (just under 5 megapixel the limit) and a file size of 5.4 MB. Is this the encoded size of the image or the decoded size of the image? And how do I figure out what the other size is?

Comment: That largely depends on what's shown in the picture. A 1500x1500 pixel PNG consisting entirely of white pixels is considerably smaller in compressed size than an actual photograph (except a photograph of an entirely white canvas). So, unless, there's something programming related to your question *and* you have code to show for this, this question might be closed as "off topic."

Comment: encoded size is the one of the file. decoded is those of raw pixels in ram (width*height*4 (if rgba) ). in `PNG` the encoded size is significantly smaller than decoded, in `BMP` its approx the same. (posting as comment, bc Q is actually offtopic)